# Win32 File Namespaces with "\\?\" not always working

Tags: .net, windows, powershell

We have very inconsistent behaviour when using the prefix "\?" to query long paths. According to the [documentation of Win32 File Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#maximum-path-length-limitation), the syntax is correct.

With exactly the same folders it works correctly one time but fails the next time without error message and no return values. When we then run it without the prefix it does return the correct meta data.

```
# NOT OK: no output, no error
Get-Item -Path '\\?\C:\Users'

# NOT OK: error - Get-Item : Illegal characters in path.
Get-Item -LiteralPath '\\?\C:\Users'

# OK: correct Get-Item output
Get-Item -Path 'C:\Users'
```

The funny thing is when we open another PowerShell window and run the same command `Get-Item -Path '\\?\C:\Users'` again, it works fine.

### UPDATE:

When we run the code below we see the meta data for the folder `c:\users` is correctly returned a couple of times and the rest are error messages about `Illegal characters in path.`

```
0..20 | ForEach-Object {
    Start-Job {
        Get-Item -LiteralPath '\\?\C:\Users'
    }
}
Get-Job | Wait-Job
Get-Job | Receive-Job
```

We're a bit stuck with this, as it's not happening all the time. Is there a way to check if the 'Win32 File Namespaces' library is correctly loaded? We're using PowerShell 5.1.

Comment: For using the "\\?\" prefix, you have to prevent PowerShell from trying to resolve wildcard `?`, so use `Get-Item -LiteralPath`. Nevertheless, it seems to be a bug that Windows PowerShell doesn't output an error on non-existing path. PowerShell Core 7 seems to have fixed the bug.

Comment: You're right about the `-LiteralPath` parameter, but still, it is an existing path so it should return the meta data.

Comment: `Get-Item -LiteralPath '\\?\C:\Users'` works for me on Windows PowerShell 5.1. The only strange thing I found is that for a non-existing path prefixed by "\\?\", no error is reported.

Comment: Your last example also works for me all the time.

Comment: We cannot replicate your issue. Unless you can provide code which reproduces the problem on other machines we cannot help. It may be the case that there is a file on that machine that doesn't work with that syntax, but we don't know that.

Comment: You could also try to replace `Get-Item -LiteralPath '\\?\C:\Users'` by `[IO.FileInfo] '\\?\C:\Users'`. If the latter works, then the bug is with PowerShell, otherwise it would be rooted in the .NET API.

Comment: @zett42 both commands issue the same errors. So it's .NET API related then. Trying to hunt this down further. Thinking anti-virus after hardening maybe...